# Styling Silverlight Telerik AppointmentDialogWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, telerik

So I am using Silverlight telerik **RadScheduler**. When creating an appointment using this control an **AppointmentDialogWindow** pops up. Now, I want to change the look of the window (i.e. its borders, frame etc.)

I am pretty good with Blend but I guess some code - behind will be necessary to set the window style for this Dialog Window.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you have the full source, go the the specific Theme folder you are looking to implement and grab the SchedulerView.xaml file from there. This is the style file for that specific control.
2. Reference this resource as a ResourceDictionary in App.xaml or the respective page you will implement the control.
3. Now when you edit this style sheet it will directly affect how the SchedulerView control operates, including it's child windows.

Warning: this is a cumbersome pain in the neck. Telerik doesn't really like people messing with their styles, and they have acknowledged that they do no typically make it easy for their existing styles to be modified.

Here is how to implement a custom theme:
http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/common-styling-apperance-themes-custom-theme-project-telerik-approach.html